# Storing Variables in Django RestAPI

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to host a rest API using Django which takes in some parameters, processes it and returns a result. For this processing to happen, I have to use certain datasets which are loaded using excel, tiff, csv, and txt files. Loading these datasets and putting them in python variables (to use them, of course) takes a bit of time; the problem is that I don't want my backend to extract info from all these files everytime I get a request. The best way I could think of is literally copying the raw values from these files and putting them in python variables using the = operator, but that would be atleast a 100,000 lines of code then. Is there some way to pre-define certain variables in my backend? i.e. a variable that would get defined on a run and then every-time I get a request, I'll just use these pre-defined variables instead of loading them again.

Comment: This is exactly what the database is for.

Comment: I can’t use a database because that would cause performance issues. I somehow need the variable to be eternally defined in python’s memory.

Comment: You cannot use a database because of _performance_ reasons? I'm really curious now about why you think the database might be too slow.

Comment: Because I'm using extremely huge numpy array and dataframes for processing on the API. Not only does this give me problems with storage (which are manageable) but deserialization of the data takes too much time. I have to finish processing in 3.5 seconds and loading one 2-D array from the DB takes about 0.75 seconds.